# Do I need to use morgan logger in production if my express app runs on heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, morgan

I'm using papertrail to view my logs. Will using `morgan` as an express middleware just slow things down? Does it serve any purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Papertral is a remote logging service. What logger (like winston) are you actually using?

Comment: So I should only use morgan for my own local development use? I'm not using any logger currently. I was using morgan as an express middleware for development.

Comment: I use papertrail with winston logger. Never faced any issues. I don't think you'd want to use morgan in production.